# How to pass ArrayList as data to Postman

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist, postman

`[ {"roleName" : "admin", "roleIds" : [1,2,3] },
     {"roleName" : "editor", "roleIds" : [4,5,6] },
     {"roleName" : "contributor", "roleIds" : [7,8,9]} ]`

My code Looks like this and the error I am getting is, "Cannot generate variable name for non-typed Collection parameter type"

Comment: Where are you trying to add this in Postman? Could you share a screenshot please.

Comment: in Body, as Raw

Comment: Is that error message returned when you try and send the request? Are you setting/saving a variable somewhere else? The question is lacking a bit of detail and context.